# Trying to add 4 days from a given day based on some data length

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to add 4 days to a date, so generate date+4 based on some data length:

```
var dateFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY";
var date = moment('20.03.2014', dateFormat);
var i = 0;
var max = this.values.length;
var labels = [];
for(i=0; i<=max; i++){
    date = date.clone().add(4,'d').format()
    labels.push(date);
}
```

But this is giving me date its not a function, any idea ?

Comment: i dont ever use moment but it looks like your format is wrong... dots instead of dashes

Comment: I updated and its giving me same error.

Comment: After the first iteration date is a string, not a moment object, so you get date.clone is not a function.

Comment: Check if `moment().isValid()`. Your moment variable may be invalid.

Comment: Sidenote; you can simplify your `for` loop (for readability) `for(var i = 0; i <= this.values.length; i++){ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You can clone a moment object using the moment function :

```
date = moment(date).add(4,'d').format()
```

here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dmdj1axb/

Comment: yes u are right, it works! I will accept the answer shortly

Comment: If this solvers your problem, can you please accept the answer (white check mark below the up/down-vote buttons) to indicate this question is answered. Thanks